# Change in response times with respect to duration of the test

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner

I just want to understand the below scenarios:

Scenario 01: When I run the test with 50 users for 10 minutes, The 90th percentile response time of transaction was 10 seconds. But, when I run the same test for 20 minutes, this time response time was 7 seconds.I have observed this change in response time multiple times. Why does response time(90th) keep on changing with change in duration of the run

Scenario 02: when the user load was 50, The response time of one particular transaction say Login was 10 seconds.But, when I run the test with 100 users, the response time of login transaction was 6 seconds. Please explain this

Answer (score 0):

You have one statistic in isolation, response time. But you have no accounting for    the use of resources which drive response time. You are also looking at very short windows and therefore smaller sample sets, are they even statistically valid? Do   you have other issues at play, such as lack of a control factor in your test design, lack of checking for expected results or a zero'd think time or pacing model - even  uncontrolled initial and in-test conditions could be impacting this and leading to results which are non-reproducible.

Consider the attached widget and what this implies for your data collection & analysis

### [image: The Performance Engineering Widget]

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple explanations, unfortunately your numbers are not enough to tell for sure what is the reason behind. The possible causes could be in:

1. [Ramp-up time](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-the-ultimate-guide). If users are arriving gradually application can adopt itself for increasing load due to [JIT compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) or [warming up caches](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/390733.html), for instance first X transactions take longer as application is not ready for them but as you continue the application performs internal optimisations therefore subsequent transactions take less time
2. The inconsistency in results might be caused by JMeter itself as if JMeter is not capable of sending requests fast enough - it will result in lower throughput and increased response times so make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)

Get used to monitor baseline OS health metrics, to wit CPU, RAM, Disk, Network, Swap usage, etc. on both application under test and JMeter side as it might be the case that there is a banal lack of resources which impacting the performance or there is another activity which consumes resources so results are not consistent. You can use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) for this.